# Centos 6.3 PERL CGI selinux file read access

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, perl, cgi, selinux

I have a CGI script called index.cgi

It is trying to read a log file called 10.128.0.242.2012.sep.20.downloaded.txt under the path /var/log/trafcount/

It appears that it is being blocked by selinux.

The audit log shows something like

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1348158321.873:1472116): avc: denied { read } for pid=11620 comm="index.cgi" name="10.128.0.242.2012.sep.20.downloaded.txt" dev=dm-0 ino=395264 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 tclass=file
```

How can I allow this script full access to all files under /var/log/trafcount ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [reading the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html).

Specifically, see the Troubleshooting section [Fixing Problems](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-Fixing_Problems) for a guide on how to use `audit2allow` to modify your local SELinux policy to permit the access your application requires.

The typical flow is:

```
audit2allow -a -M myapp
```

Inspect the policy generated to ensure that it's sane, then to install it, run:

```
semodule -i myapp.pp
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I allow this script full access to all files under
>   `/var/log/trafcount` ?

Try this:

```
chcon -R -t var_log_t /var/log/trafcount
```

Comment: It already _has_ that context.